# HERE iOS Premium Map - setAppId Crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, here-api

I have an odd crash that is happening to a minority of our users, but frequently enough to be a concern.

```
if(!NMAApplicationContext.isInitialized()) {
  NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(HERE_MAP_APP_ID, appCode: HERE_MAP_APP_CODE, licenseKey: HERE_MAP_LICENSE_KEY)
}
```

Any ideas what might cause this init call to fail?

Thanks!

Additional Info:

From our crashlytics report, 
[image: Devices with crash]

[image]

Please let me know if you need additional info.  Thanks!
Update - I was able to capture the crash in XCode.  Stacktrace:

```
frame #0: 0x00000001bd4520dc libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
frame #1: 0x00000001bd4cb094 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
frame #2: 0x00000001bd3abea8 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
frame #3: 0x0000000104724f60 NMAKit`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2248$$NMAKit + 476
```

I was able to repro it.  The code is above is called on foregrounding, and it appears that the isInitialized call is returning false on a foregrounding (not a fresh app start), so it is trying to reInit the library....and then it crashes.    Hope that helps.

Comment: Please provide more inputs like ios version number, mobile model details etc. for us to investigate.

Comment: I added some stats from our crashlytics report.  Please let me know if you need any additional info.  FYI:  this is our CDL account (yardclub-dev@googlegroups.com)  for project CatApp.  Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted.  We have a crash that is happening to that segment of our users on that particular line and I'm trying to get help from HERE tech support.  @HEREDeveloperSupport  any ideas?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code :

```
if(!NMAApplicationContext.isInitialized()) {
  NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(HERE_MAP_APP_ID, appCode: HERE_MAP_APP_CODE, licenseKey: HERE_MAP_LICENSE_KEY)
}
```

Causes crash because it has incorrect API usage:

1. Set credentials should be set before ANY HereSDK API call was used.
2. The [NMAApplicationContext](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAApplicationContext.html) doesn't provide the authorize verification methods, the NMAApplicationContext.isInitialized() checks whether map functionality is ready to use (whether engine already started). The NMAApplicationContext.isInitialized() is checked before [custom configuration setup](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMACustomConfigurations.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMACustomConfigurations(cm)setCustomConfiguration:).

**How to solve crash:**

1. Remove the NMAApplicationContext.isInitialized() if statement
2. Call the NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(HERE_MAP_APP_ID, appCode: HERE_MAP_APP_CODE, licenseKey: HERE_MAP_LICENSE_KEY) method and check the NMAApplicationContextError return value whether setup of credential was successful.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am calling setAppId before any HERE map usage, so that isn't the cause of the crash...it really is just calling it 2x. So is there way to guard against calling setAppId more than once?   I can do some housekeeping to track it, but it would be nice if there was a way to check to see if the App Context has already had the setApppId called.   Thanks again!

Comment: >So is there way to guard against calling setAppId more than once?

HERE SDK doesn't provide separate method for validation. This is not a common case, but you can store the result of NMAApplicationContext.setAppId(_:appCode: licenseKey:) as flag inside your application code and then check your flags when you need it.